# Is there any way to set media queries for specific device width and height?

Tags: css, media-queries

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (min-device-height: 480px) 

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 480px) 
and (min-device-height: 640px)
```

I just want whatever styles we set in this, it should be apply to mention height and width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to target those *exact* resolutions, you can simply drop the `min-` prefix and just specify `device-width` and `device-height`:

```
@media only screen 
    and (device-width : 320px) 
    and (device-height: 480px) { ... }

@media only screen 
    and (device-width : 480px) 
    and (device-height: 640px) { ... }
```

[W3C reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width).